# Is there a difference in performance between opencv and emgucv?

Tags: opencv, emgucv

If there is , is it a significant difference?

Is the difference derived by the different languages (c# vs c++)?

The libraries implementations?

Both?

That is for all operations , 
and especially image pixels iteration.

Comment: I've been looking into this a bit today, it amazes me that people have gone to the trouble of building an entire managed wrapper but not profiling it. From what I can tell is it should be *largely* the same under real world conditions...